# In Snowflake, How to update the data in the table which is present in other schema using procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

```
var run_id_query = `INSERT INTO STG.RUN_STATUS (RUNID,STATUS,STATUS_DESCRIPTION)
VALUES (TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE,'YYYYMMDD'),0,'RUN START')`;
var run_id_stmt = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: run_id_query});
var run_id = run_id_stmt.execute();
```

getting error SQL compilation error: **syntax error line 3 at position 8 unexpected 'ID_DEV'.**

insert is present in STG schema, i am trying to insert it from INT schema

Comment: There is no limitation to updating the data in another schema. Can you share the whole script? The one you shared doesn't have anything with INT schema.

Answer (score 0):

Could you break it down e.g.:

```
 run_id_query = $$INSERT INTO STG.RUN_STATUS (RUNID,STATUS,STATUS_DESCRIPTION) VALUES (TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE,'YYYYMMDD'),0,'RUN START')$$;
 execute immediate $run_id_query
```

[image]